# Playframework SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

Im trying to make a query that help me get a user by its username. What i want to do is to check if the given username is unique. so what i thought about is to uppercase the username when i do my select request and compare it with an uppercase of the given username. This is what i tried:

```
SQL("select * from utilisateur where upper(pseudo) = {pseudo}").on(
        'pseudo -> pseudo.toUpperCase
        ).as(Utilisateur.utilisateur.singleOpt)
```

but it get this error:

```
[RuntimeException: SqlMappingError(too many rows when expecting a single one)]
```

I tried this too:

```
SQL("select * from utilisateur where ucase(pseudo) = {pseudo}").on(
        'pseudo -> pseudo.toUpperCase
        ).as(Utilisateur.utilisateur.singleOpt)
```

and i got this error:

```
[PSQLException: ERROR: function ucase(character varying) does not exist Indice : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position : 33]
```

What should i do ?

PS:Im using PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in Play!, only use `singleOpt` if you're expecting exactly one row back. Otherwise, it will throw an exception. Since you *do* want just one row, add a `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query.

The PostgreSQL function you want is `upper()`. Here's an example:

```
SQL("select * from utilisateur where upper(pseudo) = {pseudo} limit 1").on(
        'pseudo -> pseudo.toUpperCase
        ).as(Utilisateur.utilisateur.singleOpt)
```

(You can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6226c/5)

Comment: Thank you this worked fine for me.As you said the problem was coming from `singleOpt` because its getting more than one row when its excpecting only one.